# jQuery autocomplete select does not work

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

In autocomplete property select I can't insert the selected value to the input text.  Even using `$(this)` and `$(#inputname)` still does't work.

What am I doing wrong?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var strMe = {
        "vntret": [
            { "e_city": "CITY1", "e_province": "PROVINCE1" }, 
            { "e_city": "CITY2", "e_province": "PROVINCE2" }
        ]
    }

    $("#txtAddressL2").autocomplete({
        source: strMe,
        source: function (request, response) {
            //how to filtering just skipped
            {
                response(strMe.vntret);
            }
        },
        minLength: 3,
        select: function (event, ui) {
            $(this).val(ui.item.e_city);
            //event this command doesnt works as well
            $("#txtAddressL2").val(ui.item.e_city);
        }
    }).data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
        return $("<li></li>").data("item.autocomplete", item)
            .append("<a>" + item.e_city + "<br>" + item.e_province + "</a>")
            .appendTo(ul);
    }
});
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ph345qpk/2/)

Answer (score 1):

resolved by add after insert the value to selector.

```
 return false;
```

here is the updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ph345qpk/3/)